Turning off "Offer to save passwords" doesn't work
After turning off "Offer to save passwords" by following the instructions on https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6197437?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid, all Android apps still keep prompting me to save password whenever I log in to an app for the first time. Are there any other settings to look at to turn off this prompt?

Maybe, it's the Google password managery. Try disabling from settings(offer to save password)//As in the link quoted both Chrome and password manager offer to save passwords
